# ¿Como puedo crear un caja de texto con un valor inicial de 0, y dos botones uno que sume y otro que deje el valor a 0 de nuevo en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase y voy bastante perdido. Si alguien me pudiese indicar como se soluciona se lo agradeceria.

Este seria el html y va acompañado de un js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Titulo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./codigo3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="valor">
    <input type="button" id="sumar" onclick="sumar()">
    <input type="button" id="reinicio" onclick="reinicio()">
</body>
</html>
```

Y este el js:

```
var valor="0";
document.getElementById('valor');
valor.innerHTML;
function suma() {
    valor=valor++;
}

function reinicio() {
    valor=0;
}
```

Comment: ¿cual es el código con el que estas probando y que te ha fallado?

Comment: Busca algún tutorial y parte de ahi, modificandolo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero debes declarar los valores que vas a editar desde las funciones.
valor y divValor. Donde valor es el contador y el divValor es el elemento visual del HTML.

Creamos la función sumar y reinicio. donde modificamos el valor(contador) y indicamos al divValor que queremos dentro de el. en este caso el valor.

Y para terminar creamos una función que se va ejecutar cuando la ventana este cargada. Que es donde vamos a setear el div ya que si lo haces antes javascript no va a encontrar el div.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Titulo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var valor = "0";
      var divValor = null;
      function sumar() {
        valor = ++valor;
        divValor.innerHTML = valor;
      }

      function reinicio() {
        valor = 0;
        divValor.innerHTML = valor;
      }
      function init() {
        divValor = document.getElementById("valor");
        divValor.innerHTML = valor;
      }
      window.onload = init;
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="valor"></div>
    <input type="button" id="sumar" onclick="sumar()" />
    <input type="button" id="reinicio" onclick="reinicio()" />
  </body>
</html>
```